# Am I protected against SQL injections?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-injection

I have been attacked on my last few questions here for writing code that is open to injections. I am looking for honest help to make sure I am finally doing this the safest and correct way. Please give me any tips to make this as secure as possible.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT dbo.Table (FullName, Category, Street, City, State, Zip, PhoneDay, PhoneEven, Email, Employer, Description, UserName, 
                                                  UserStreet, UserCity, UserState, UserZip, UserPhoneDay, UserPhoneEven, UserEmail, SubmitDate) 
                                                  VALUES (@f1, @f2, @f3, @f4, @f5, @f6, @f7, @f8, @f9, @f10, @f11, @f12, @f13, @f14, @f15, @f16, @f17, @f18, @f19, @f20)", conn);
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = NameTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = HeroicList.SelectedValue;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f3", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = StreetTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f4", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = CityTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f5", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = StateTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f6", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = ZipTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f7", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = PhoneDayTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f8", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = PhoneEvenTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f9", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = EmailTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f10", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = EmpTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f11", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = WhyTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f12", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserNameTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f13", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserStreetTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f14", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserCityTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f15", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserStateTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f16", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserZipTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f17", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserPhoneDayTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f18", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserPhoneEvenTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f19", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = UserEmailTxtBox.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@f20", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                messageLabel.Text = "Your submission has been sent!";
                messageLabel.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                messageLabel.Text = ex.Message;
                messageLabel.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is HTML markup doing inside a persistence class?  You should be flogged for that as well.

Comment: Looks safe from SQL-injection to me.  Through outputting the error message to the user isn't a safe thing to do.

Comment: @Matthew Thanks Matt I will make that change.

Comment: SQL Injection prevention just says that .. don't pass parameter as concatenated string rather pass them as sqlparameter; so that, even if some one injecting something it will be taken as parameter and will not be considered as separate query by sql engine altogether. So from that point of view you are pretty much safe.

Comment: Off Topic but it may also help: If this is a web app, make sure that you HtmlEncode any text that was originally entered by a user. So all of this data from the Textboxes should be encoded when displayed on the page.

Comment: @KeithPayne Thanks keith, good point I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're protected with respect to insertion, yes.  Using your code, it doesn't matter what the user puts in any of the textboxes (or what they put in any other sort of response they can cook up) nothing will happen beyond their data being stuck into fields of a new row of the given table, exactly as the strings were given to you.

The only way (that comes to mind) that someone could maliciously inject code would depend on how you use the data once it's in the database.  If you go and, for example, take a field from this table and stick it in a `LiteralControl` without escaping anything and show it to other users then someone could stick in nasty JavaScript code that they run on another person's machine, for example.  That would be a "cross site scripting" attack.  To prevent that you need to make sure that any user-inputted data is sanitized before being displayed.